# Query to find available timeslots

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called appointments and a table called shifts. In the table appointments, there is the shift_id, so it looks something like this:

`id | start_date | end_date | shift_id ( FK )`

An example shift is 09:00 to 17:00 and it contains a couple of appointments in it:

`09:30 - 10:10 | 11:30 - 11:50 | 13:00 - 14:00`

I am currently using this query to get the available time slots, but it has an edge case issue. It does not find the start from 9 - 9:30.

```sql
SELECT Available_from, Available_to
        FROM (
        SELECT @lasttime_to AS Available_from, start_date AS Available_to, @lasttime_to := end_date
        FROM (SELECT start_date, end_date
               FROM appointments
                WHERE shift_id = " . $shiftData->id . "
                AND end_date <= '" . $shiftData->end_date->toDateTimeString() . "'
                AND start_date >= '" . $shiftData->start_date->toDateTimeString() . "'
               UNION ALL
             SELECT '". $shiftData->start_date->toDateTimeString() ."', '". $shiftData->start_date->toDateTimeString() ."'
                   ORDER BY end_date 
        
             ) e
        JOIN (SELECT @lasttime_to := NULL) init) x
        WHERE Available_to > DATE_ADD(Available_from, INTERVAL " . $serviceDurations . " MINUTE)
```

What's missing in this? How can I get the start to show up in the query?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5292d/2

Comment: Could you add the table of shifts to your question, plus add at least one shift to the table?  Then adjust your attempt to use that shifts table.  That might help push the solution toward a query which resolves the problem without iterating over a query and without potential injections.  The `shift_id` may turn out to be unnecessary, since the start / end times will probably determine which shift an appointment applies to.  If you have overlapping shifts, that's a different story.

Comment: *in the table appointments, there is the shift_id so it looks something like this* Provide this as complete CREATE TABLE (and add ref. table too). *An example shift is 09:00 to 17:00 and it contains a couple of appointments in it* Provide this as INSERT INTO (3-5 rows). *I am currently using this query to get the available time slots but it has an edge case issue. It does not find the start from 9 - 9:30* Provide criteria (definite timerange) and desired output for provided sample data and criteria.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  That can be a factor.   Here's another question which has a solution that could be applied to your problem.  It's a scheduling problem, much like yours.  But it identifies the remaining `Shift` times (within the schedule) in an interesting way.  The solution adjusted to your example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e8a60feefae81c17cdf171e60345a252   ... The related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70311968/find-highest-ranked-pieces-of-intersecting-rows-in-sql/70321139#70321139

Comment: It would be fairly easy to apply the above solution to your schema as well.  Let me know if you're interested in something like that.  I guess the first hurdle is whether you're using MySQL 8.0+ or MariaDB 2.2+, both of which mark initial releases with support for the SQL constructs required for this solution.

Comment: Here is an SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5292d/2

Comment: Are you using MySQL 5.6?  `SELECT version();`  will show the version.

Comment: No, I use mysql 8.0

Comment: For your SQL, I think you'll find the initial row is generated with a NULL `Available_from`, which will never pass the WHERE clause.  Notice: `SELECT @lasttime_to AS Available_from ...`

Comment: I've answered your direct question in my answer.  See the top of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to address your original SQL (in the fiddle).

For the first row, `@lasttime_to` is NULL and causes problems.

Need to use the "shift start time" conditionally for the null case (first row).

See `LAG` for another approach.  That's really what the `@variable` hack is trying to replace, before `LAG` was available in MySQL.

Try this:

```sql
SELECT Available_from, Available_to
  FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE(@lasttime_to, '2022-03-15 10:00:00') AS Available_from, start_date AS Available_to, @lasttime_to := end_date
    FROM (SELECT start_date, end_date
             FROM appointments
             WHERE shift_id = 4600
             AND end_date <= '2022-03-15 17:00:00'
             AND start_date >= '2022-03-15 10:00:00'
             UNION ALL
               SELECT '2022-03-15 17:00:00', '2022-03-15 17:00:00'
               ORDER BY start_date 
           ) e
    JOIN (SELECT @lasttime_to := NULL) init) x
    WHERE Available_to > DATE_ADD(Available_from, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
;
```

The result:

| Available_from | Available_to |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-15 10:00:00 | 2022-03-15 10:30:00 |
| 2022-03-15 12:15:00 | 2022-03-15 15:00:00 |
| 2022-03-15 15:40:00 | 2022-03-15 17:00:00 |

Here's something with window functions too.  I've rearranged the logic to avoid multiple magic constants related to your shift start/end detail.  I didn't remove all the magic, however.

I still prefer the more dynamic approach that I removed.

```sql
WITH shift (shift_start, shift_end) AS (
       SELECT '2022-03-15 10:00:00', '2022-03-15 17:00:00'
     )
   , e0 AS (
       SELECT shift_id, start_date, end_date
         FROM appointments
        WHERE shift_id = 4600
          AND end_date   <= (SELECT shift_end   FROM shift)
          AND start_date >= (SELECT shift_start FROM shift)
        UNION ALL
       SELECT 4600, shift_end, shift_end FROM shift
        ORDER BY start_date 
     )
   , e AS (
      SELECT e0.*
           , LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY shift_id ORDER BY start_date) AS lasttime_to
        FROM e0
     )
SELECT shift_id, Available_from, Available_to
  FROM (
       SELECT shift_id
            , CAST(COALESCE(lasttime_to, shift_start) AS datetime) AS Available_from
            , start_date AS Available_to
         FROM e
         CROSS JOIN shift
      ) x
 WHERE Available_to > DATE_ADD(Available_from, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
;
```

Slightly different version:

```sql
WITH e0 AS (
       SELECT a.shift_id, a.start_date, a.end_date
            , s.start_date AS shift_start
            , s.end_date   AS shift_end
         FROM appointments AS a
         JOIN shifts       AS s
           ON a.shift_id = 4600
          AND a.shift_id = s.id
          AND a.end_date   <= s.end_date
          AND a.start_date >= s.start_date
        UNION
       SELECT id, end_date, end_date
            , start_date  , end_date
         FROM shifts WHERE id = 4600
     )
   , e AS (
      SELECT e0.*
           , LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY shift_id ORDER BY start_date) AS lasttime_to
        FROM e0
     )
SELECT shift_id, Available_from, Available_to
  FROM (
       SELECT shift_id
            , CAST(COALESCE(lasttime_to, shift_start) AS datetime) AS Available_from
            , start_date AS Available_to
         FROM e
      ) x
 WHERE Available_to > DATE_ADD(Available_from, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
;
```

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0f454e8afd3c988b9c23d1a11e5ebe3)

Comment: i get the approach but i don't want overlapping appointments, Also i do not with to use another table i just want to get the free slots in the range

Comment: @FilipStojkovski The point is you do have overlapping tasks, in a sense.  The `Shift` is a task which is then interrupted by any scheduled appointments.  This logic tracks the broken up Shifts in just the way you need.  The tasklist table is not required.  You can easily create a tasklist CTE term and refer to your tables directly. If you're interested, let me know.  The approach is identical, with or without the tasklist table.

Comment: @FilipStojkovski There's no requirement to add overlapping "appointments".  This approach handles that general case too.  The update I've made uses your data directly, with no additional table... and shows how you can find all remaining/available shift ranges or just the first, if that's all you want.

Comment: @FilipStojkovski I've removed the other suggestion.

Comment: @FilipStojkovski I prefer not to inject into SQL. The more general solution is a bit more in line with declarative SQL.  The `@variable` approach was helpful (but still a hack) before window functions were available.  You might want to consider window functions instead.

Comment: Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/278102b/6

Comment: This works on the fiddle but in my database it still shows the 10:00 10:30 slot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242231/discussion-between-filip-stojkovski-and-jon-armstrong).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=409db6dd827acd7bda4ff9723fa108d9